# cycle graph with $10$ v colouring with $11$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $a$ be the number of ways in which $C10$ the cycle graph with $10$ vertices can be coloured with $11$ colours and let $b$ be the number of ways $K11$ , the complete graph with $11$ vertices, can be coloured with $20$ colours.

(a) Write $a$ and $b$ as the product of powers of prime numbers.
Hint: there is just a single prime factor of a that is greater than $25$.

(b) Find the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

(c) Find the lowest common multiple of a and b.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The Chromatic polynomial $P(x)$ of $K_n$ is known. Evaluate it at $20$. The factorization comes easily from the formula.

If you don't know yet the Chromatic polynomial of $C_{10}$ yet you can calculate it by deletion-contraction. For the factorization, the hint makes it easy: find all primes less than 25, and their powers in this number.